# how to redirect to another .aspx page on clicking on a rectangle on a .aspx page?

Tags: vb.net

how to redirect to another .aspx page on clicking on a rectangle on a .aspx page?plz mention the whole program including headers, preferably in vb

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ImageMap control to do what you're looking for. Image maps allow you to define portions of an image (as rectangles, if you wish) and then define which URL the browser will navigate to for each particular 'clickable region' of the map you create!

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagemap.aspx for further information on how to use the ImageMap control.